Write a new Delphi type that lets a method have inline code as a parameter?
Is it possible to have this in Delphi?
DoThis(ShowMessage('SomeMsg ..'); Caption := 'SomeCaption'; Inc(I));

Is it possible to create a new type that handles inline code like this?
For example, we have TProc in Delphi, but it has procedure begin and end as mandatory.
Is it possible to write a new Delphi type that recognize inline code?

No, that is not possible.

You don't get to invent syntax

The exact syntax you are looking for is simply not possible, no.  You are constrained to the Pascal/Delphi language syntax, which does not allow inline code in a parameter.
The closest you can get is with an Anonymous Method (D2009+), as you already noted, eg (for future reference):
// type TProc = reference to procedure;

procedure DoThis(AProc: TProc);
begin
  AProc();
end;

DoThis(procedure
begin
  ShowMessage('SomeMsg ..');
  Caption := 'SomeCaption';
  Inc(I);
end);

